# Can we get multiple responses from controller to view (ajax-mvc)?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on registration module. Flow is like:

1. Save data in the database.
2. Notify user that data has been saved.
3. Send password in email.
4. Again update UI. Like, the password has been sent an email.

I wanted to do this in a single UI call to the server.
Step-1 and Step-3 have been completed. But I don't know how can I accomplish step -2 and step -4 asynchronously.

Here is the code:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> CheckUserNameAndInsert(Guid BusinessId, string username, string Email)
    {
    // save data in db
            LoginViewModel loginViewModel = new LoginViewModel();
            loginViewModel.Username = username;
            loginViewModel.BuisnessID = BusinessId;
            loginViewModel.Email = Email;  
            ReturnType returnResult = SaveData(loginViewModel);


    // send response to notify user that data has been saved.
            returnResult.isSent = false;
            var obj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(returnResult);
            Response.Write(obj);
            Response.Flush();

    //Sending password in email
                IEmailManagement em = new EmailManagement();

    //I am making async call to "em.SendPassword" method.
                var task = em.SendPassword(returnResult.Email, returnResult.Password);  
        var isEmailSend = await task;

                returnResult.isSent = isEmailSend;
        obj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(returnResult);
    //Notifying user about sent email.
                Response.Write(obj);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();

            return Json(new { data = returnResult }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

I get only one response after completion of both tasks.

Comment: why not set one message saying "Data has been saved, you should receive an email shortly", why do you need two notifications?

Comment: Pretty sure because `return Json(new { data = returnResult }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` is the only one that get sent back to the client. What you're looking for is more like a push notification such as WebSocket/SignalR have a look at those.

Comment: @KarthikGanesan I need to know if email has been sent or not. let's suppose email get's stuck then user will have to wait for the response.

Comment: @penleychan I know SignalR notification but i wanted to do by using aysnc methods.

Comment: You're out of luck for that, AFAIK that's not possible with a single call. You'd have to do multiple ajax callbacks.

Comment: @penleychan Thanks for your suggestion I got your point.

Comment: The two steps are part of one operation from the point of view of the user. He/She should expect an e-mail but doesn't need to know if the operation to send it actually succeeded. If they don't get one, they will complain and you will go figure out what went wrong.

Comment: Alternatively, you can wrap both as one atomic operation and fail both if something goes wrong, then rollback the saving of the user, but I wouldn't recommend that since the e-mail is a recoverable step that can be triggered again.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a solution to your direction question, but this is how I'd build something to do this:

First- Create an events table with columns for a transaction ID, action, and status.

The user will interact with a button to save the data.

Page calls your controller, and is assigned a transaction ID. This is returned to your calling page.

Internally, the controller then calls separate methods to save the data, and send emails. It passes the assigned transaction ID to each method.

When each method succeeds, it updates events table with the transaction ID, a status, and associated action.

Back in the calling page, with the transaction ID now in hand, your page start polling a different method to check the events table for the given action and status. It can check every second, every five seconds, what have you.

When the events table is updated, you can update the UI on the page to indicate that the action has happened.

You can use the events table for a variety of things, as well, beyond this single functionality. Short of adding Signal R or Meteor, or having a full scale product to handle queued events, this should get the job done for you.

So the user hits a single button, and the page updates as the actions are completed.